# How to create .rtf and edit in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, rtf

I have two UIImageView and two textfiled under the image view. One textfield for image1 and second textfield for image2.

Now I want that user enter text and give image name and that image will save in document directory in .rtf format. And the when I open .rtf I will be able to edit that rtf.

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,50, 100, 100)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,150, 100, 100)];
[imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
self.view imageView1];
[imageView1 release];




txt=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,190, 180, 30)];
txt.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
txt.placeholder=@"Enter Text";
txt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txt.delegate =self;
[txt addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageSave_method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
txt.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
txt.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
txt.autocapitalizationType = NO;
txt.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
[self.view addSubview:txt];



txt2=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,190, 180, 30)];
txt2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
txt2.placeholder=@"Enter Text";
txt2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txt2.delegate =self;
[txt2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageSave_method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
txt2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
txt2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
txt2.autocapitalizationType = NO;
txt2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
[self.view addSubview:txt2];
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Any Idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say you want the user to give an image name and save the image in RTF format? Please edit or describe again what you want to achieve. RTF is a microsoft format for formatted text, not for images. Why do you need RTF? What do you need the formatting information for, at all? How will the RTF file be used?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the nsuserdefaults to saved the image name

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefault setObject:_imageName1 forKey:@"imageName1"];
    [userDefault setObject: _imageName2 forKey:@"imageName2"];
    [userDefault synchronize];
```

for retrieving the data from nsuserdefaults

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *_imageName1 = [userDefault objectForKey:@"imageName1"];
    NSString *_imageName2 = [userDefault objectForKey:@"imageName2"];
```

to save the image in documents directory

1. create the file path

   ```
   NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
       NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *imagePath1 =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageName1.png",
       docDir];
   ```
2. convert the UIImage into nsdata

   ```
   NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image);
   ```
3. then save the image into imagePath1 of document directory

   ```
   [data writeToFile:imagePath1 atomically:YES];
   ```

for retrieving the image

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath1];
```